# conditions for the inacurate floating point in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have data frame:

```
df = pd.df('C:\\...\\file.csv')
```

and I calculate ratio of two continiuos(numeric) columns:

```
df['var_3'] = df['var_1']/df['var_2']
```

then i want to do the following:

```
def var_4(row):
  if row ['var_3']>=0 and row ['var_3']<5:
      return 'A'
  elif row ['var_3']<0 or row ['var_3']>=5:
      return 'B'

df['var_4'] = df.apply(lambda row: var_4(row),axis = 1)
```

The problem is, that couple of values in `var_3` column are equal 5.0(python shows such value). But insead of returning `'B'`, it returns me value `'A'`.
How can I fix it?

I checked, that the difference,forexample, between one such values and number 5 is `8.881784e-16`

Comment: How can `row ['var_3']<0 and row ['var_3']>=5` ever happen? A number cannot be less than 0 and greater than or equal to 5 at the same time...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry, it was a missprint. But the problem is still the same

Comment: why not comparing to 5.0 then ?

Comment: @Trolldejo unforunately,it doesn't help, There is the difference between some number in column var_3 and 5 which is equal to -8.8817484e-16.

Comment: When you say there's a tiny difference between your raw value and the number five, are you saying that it's very slightly *below* 5 (thus 'A') or very slightly *above* 5 (thus 'B')? That is -- is the math behaving correctly (below 5) but you want to round it to 5 exactly, or is the value above 5 and still returning 'A' somehow?

Comment: Follow-up: If you print the raw example value at the start of this method, what does it show? (That is, is the value being rounded upon parsing the csv? When you cite the example value are you looking at the raw csv or inspecting the value as Python understands it?)